# What returns SQLite_exec() at SQLite API for C++

Tags: c++, sqlite

Is there explanation what means value, that is returned by function [sqlite_exec()](http://www.sqlite.org/c3ref/exec.html) at SQLite API for C++?

Comment: Wasn't this stated in the SQLite documentation you have linked? It returns error codes. Please spend a bit more research efforts before asking here.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

It returns an [error code](http://www.sqlite.org/rescode.html). If it's something other than `SQLITE_OK`, then something went wrong.

Also, the function you linked to is the official *C* API for SQLite. There is no official C++ API.

Answer (score 0):

The [documentation](http://www.sqlite.org/c3ref/exec.html) says:

> The sqlite3_exec() interface is a convenience wrapper around [sqlite3_prepare_v2()](http://www.sqlite.org/c3ref/prepare.html), [sqlite3_step()](http://www.sqlite.org/c3ref/step.html), and [sqlite3_finalize()](http://www.sqlite.org/c3ref/finalize.html).

It can return any of the [error codes](http://www.sqlite.org/rescode.html) from these functions.